# What does the diamond on Mister Sinister's forehead do?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mister-sinister

As far as I remember, Mister Sinister has had a Red Diamond on his forehead, such as this image from 1989.

[image: Mister Sinister from 1989]

I can't find anything online to explain this gem. Is it just aesthetics, or does it serve a purpose?

Comment: It's called fashion, dahlink. You vouldn't understand.

Comment: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/mr-sinister/4005-3179/forums/red-diamond-of-mister-sinisters-forehead-583437/

Comment: @Valorum I saw that before posting, but I don't have access to that to know it's the reason. Also, who's to say I don't have my own fashionable head diamond ‍♂️

Comment: Under your top hat?

Comment: It's the focusing lens for his beam weapon